# How to delete record where date is too close?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, sql-delete

I have a redshift table and I would like to delete records for whose timestamp are too close.

For the following table, I would like to delete line 3 and 4 because date is close to line 1 and other fields are identical.

```
 col1  |   col2   |  col3
--------------------------
  1       02:23       4
  51      02:23      29
  1       02:22       4
  1       02:24       4
  1       19:57       4
```

Comment: How close is too close? If two rows are too close, which one should be kept?

Comment: Too close is +- 5 min. I don't care which record is kept, but not all deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . You can use `lead()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lead(col2) over (partition by col1, col3 over order by col2) as next_col2
      from t
     ) t
where next_col2 is null or
      next_col2 < col2 + interval '1 hour'. -- or whatever your cutoff is
```